# datetime is coming instead of date in python

Tags: python

This is my create method

```
def create(cls, data):
        try:
            cls.format_date_only_element(data,'start_date')
            cls.format_date_only_element(data,'end_date')            
            promotion = cls(**data)      
            promotion.save()
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

in above code `formate_date_only_element` method is

```
 _date_only_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
 def format_date_only_element(cls,data,date_field):        
        for r in data:        
            if date_field in r:                                
                pdate =  datetime.strptime(data[date_field], cls._date_only_format)
                data[date_field]=pdate
                break
```

and my create handler is
 def post(self):
        self__uploads = None
        form = forms.CreatePromotion(self.request.POST)
        count = Promotion.all().count()
        if count==0:
            count=1
        form.display_order.choices = [(item+1, item+1) for item in range(count)]
        image = self.get_uploads('image')
        video = self.get_uploads('video')
        if form.validate():
            data = form.data
            log.info(data)
            upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/admin/promotion/create')
            try:
                datetime.strptime(data['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
                datetime.strptime(data['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                self.session.add_flash("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD",key='error')
                return self.render_response("/admin/promotion/create.html", form=form, upload_url=upload_url)

```
        supp_code=data['supplier_code']
        supplier_obj=SupplierMaster.get_by_code(supp_code)

        supp_code1=data['supplier_code']
        supplier_obj1=Supplier.get_by_code(supp_code1)

        if not supplier_obj and supplier_obj1 is None:
            self.session.add_flash('Supplier code does not exist',key='error')
            return self.render_response("/admin/promotion/create.html", form=form, upload_url=upload_url)

        else:
            is_video = bool(video)
            is_image = bool(image)
            if not is_image and not is_video:                
                self.session.add_flash("Please select a video or image",key='error')                
                return self.render_response("/admin/promotion/create.html", form=form, upload_url=upload_url)
            else:
                del data['video']
                del data['image']                
                if is_video:
                    if video[0].content_type.startswith('video'):
                        log.info("is video")
                        data['video'] = video[0]
                    else:
                        log.info("is_video")
                        self.session.add_flash("Please select a video or image",key='error')
                        return self.redirect("/admin/promotion/create") 
                if is_image:
                    if image[0].content_type.startswith('image'):
                        log.info("is image")
                        data['image'] = image[0]
                    else:
                        log.info("is_image")
                        self.session.add_flash("Please select a video or image",key='error')
                        return self.redirect("/admin/promotion/create")

                flag = Promotion.create(data)
                if flag is True:
                    self.session.add_flash('Promotion created successfully!',key='success')
                else:
                    self.session.add_flash("Error occured in creating Promotion",key='error')
            return self.redirect("/admin/promotions")
    else:
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/admin/promotion/create')
        return self.render_response("/admin/promotion/create.html", form=form, upload_url=upload_url)
```

its giving output like(2015-10-29 00:00:00) but i want my out put only date not date time , thanks in advance

Comment: How are you checking the output? Are you converting the datetime to string anywhere?

Comment: What is the value of: data[date_field], if it is a string for example. "2015-10-22" then the code is giving you the correct output. If you want to convert a datetime object into a string you should use datetime.strftime(datetime_object, "%Y-%m-%d"), this will give you the required result.

Comment: yes prateek its giving "2015-10-22" but when it comes to create method like ...flag = Promotion.create(data) here it showing "2015-10-22 00-00-00"

Comment: @Uday: Can you please post your Promotion model class. I think you have mentioned that date field as DateTimeField that's why it is giving the datetime string.

Comment: yes prateek i mentioned datetime field in model but i am using strip

Comment: class Promotion(db.Model, ModelMixin):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    image = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
    video = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
    supplier_code = db.StringProperty()    
    start_date = db.DateTimeProperty()
    end_date = db.DateTimeProperty()

Comment: yes prateek your correct.....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.date()` on the datetime object to get the date -

```
pdate =  datetime.strptime(data[date_field], cls._date_only_format).date()
```

Comment: again its giving datetime not date